# Sensortower daterangepicker set min max during period

Tags: javascript, daterangepicker

I use https://sensortower.github.io/daterangepicker/

[image]

I want to disable `Apr, May, Jun`

So can select `Jan - Mar` and `Jul- Nov`

How can i set ?
Thankyou